# Product rule for limits of scalar products

Tags: calculus, limits

How do we prove:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{0}}[r_1(t) \cdot r_2(t)]=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{0}}[r_1(t)] \cdot \lim_{t\rightarrow t_{0}}[r_2(t)]
\end{equation*}

where $r_1(t)$ and $r_2(t)$ are vector functions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined in a deleted neighborhood of $t_0,$ assuming they both have limits at $t_0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scalar product is a sum of products, namely $r_{1,x}\cdot r_{2,x} + r_{1,y}\cdot r_{2,y}+ r_{1,z}\cdot r_{2,z}$. Now, sums and products can be [moved out of the limit](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/calculus/limprop/limprop.html) as long as the individual limits exist:

$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} [r_1(t) \cdot r_2(t)]
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} [r_{1,x}(t)\cdot r_{2,x}(t) + r_{1,y}(t)\cdot r_{2,y}(t)+ r_{1,z}(t)\cdot r_{2,z}(t)] \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} r_{1,x}(t) \cdot \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} r_{2,x}(t) + \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} r_{1,y}(t) \cdot \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} r_{2,y}(t)
+ \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} r_{1,z}(t) \cdot \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} r_{2,z}(t) \\
&= \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} r_1(t) \cdot  \lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} r_2(t).
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Is it also work for the cross product?

Comment: I think if also does, because the cross product is also a sum of products of component functions